# openGL Glut - arcball rotation using matrices multiplier

Tags: opengl, graphics, glut, linear-algebra

I'm having a "5am problem" with my code.
 My program has to display a 3d model and I need to rotate using the arcball method
 so far everything i calculated was ok ( i believe...)
 what I want to happen next is that every time i drag the curser ( which created the vectors)
 the model will keep rotating from where it is.

I tried using the getFloatv and mult it but was with no success
the model keeps returning to its starting point of view .
Note : I've used push and pop matrix command in every function so no mess will be done
you could say the real question is how to use this quatrainon and matrix multiply 
to add rotations to one another
so is there anything missing? or anything missplaced?

thanks,

**EDIT :::::::::::::::: updated code:**

Hey, thanks for answering but i still have a problem
i tried using an if statement to only multmatrix when the rotation is done
but then there is no continuous rotation, it just jumps to the beginning every time

```
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,_oldRotationsQuatro);

glTranslatef(0.f,0.f,DRAWFARONZAXIS);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT |  GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // Modeling transformation

glLoadIdentity();
glColor3d(1,1,1);

drawObject(model);

glRotated(model->getCurrRotatingAngle(),model->getRotatingAroundVector().getX(),
    model->getRotatingAroundVector().getY(),
    model->getRotatingAroundVector().getZ());

// if (end rotate)
    glMultMatrixf(_oldRotationsQuatro);

drawCamera();

glPopMatrix();
```

good rotation but super speed...

**EDIT**
Thanks i figured something out. the glmultmatrix doesnt work exactly as i thought
so i just added another matrix and used some old savings.

thanks!

Comment: still no solution, the drawing goes nuts....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is compute a rotation matrix `offset` from the angle/axis representation you have. When you stop dragging, you need to store this matrix as `rotation` in your `model` object. When you start dragging again, you first apply the `rotation`, and then the `offset` with `glMultMatrix`. When you stop dragging, you multiply `offset` onto `rotation`. Pseudo code:

- Initialization: Set `rotation` to identity.
- While dragging: Compute `offset` from axis/angle, `glMultMatrix(rotation); glMultMatrix(offset)`.
- Stop dragging: Set `rotation = rotation * offset`.

Comment: edited the topic since this box is too small for code.
still a problem, rotation can be continuous iff i multmatrix
every loop, but it does it really fast...
if i use an if function and only multmatrix when rotation is over
i get to rotate from the beginning the next rotate instead of the saved one

Comment: Don't use `glGetFloatv`. Like, ever. :) As I wrote, you have to store the base rotation matrix yourself, OpenGL can't do that for you. If you don't want to handle the matrix/rotation stuff yourself, I would suggest glm.